# Ansible Nested Variable Regex search

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

How do we do a wildcard search with Ansible nested variable?

YAML

```
test:
  name:
    address:
         zipcode: 12345
```

Ansible Template Variable

```
{{ test[name][addre*].zipcode }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do we do a wildcard search with Ansible nested variable?

```
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ test.name
      | dict2items
      | selectattr("key", "match", "addr.*")
      | map(attribute="value.zipcode")
      | list }}
```

Where `dict2items` explodes the children of `name` allowing one to pattern match -- or any other fun tricks -- based on the **key** of the `dict`, which ordinarily -- as you have seen -- isn't possible

Then we now have a list of matching `{"key": "address1234", "value": {"zipcode": "11111"}}` structures, so if you want the `zipcode` field of all of them, just reach into the `value` dict and pull out its `zipcode` field.

The final `list` is a concession because `map` produces a python generator, and not an actual list